# Storing values of texts files in list of lists

Tags: java

I have the following text file:

```
1 ---------------------------------------------------
int int0 = (-2586);
int int1 = 3580;
int int2 = 2315;
int int3 = (-1974);
2 ---------------------------------------------------
int int0 = (-2586);
int int1 = 3580;
int int2 = 2315;
int int3 = (-1974);
3 ---------------------------------------------------
int int0 = (2586);
int int1 = 3580;
int int2 = 2315;
int int3 = (-1974);
```

I would like to store the integer values of each set (i.e., 3 sets in the example) in a list and store all the lists in one list. To do this:

```
    BufferedReader reader;

    ArrayList<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

    List<Integer> objSuite = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file1.txt"));

        String line = reader.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            if(line.contains("------")) {
                list.add(objSuite);
                objSuite = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            }

            if(line.contains("int int")) {
                Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*?(-?\\d+)\\D*$");
                Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
                if (m.matches()) {
                    objSuite.add(Integer.parseInt(m.group(1)));
                }
            }

            line = reader.readLine();
        }

        reader.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When I run this code, I get the following results:

```
[]
[-2586, 3580, 2315, -1974]
[-2586, 3580, 2315, -1974]
```

What I expect is the following result:

```
[-2586, 3580, 2315, -1974]
[-2586, 3580, 2315, -1974]
[2568, 3580, 2315, -1974]
```

The current implementation does not include the values of the third set. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: You put `list.add(objSuite)` and `objSuite = new ArrayList<Integer>()` in the wrong order.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're adding to your list at the beginning of your loop.

Add a `list.add(objSuite);` after your loop finishes, or consider moving it in your function to avoid entering an empty object as the first element of your array.

Comment: The issue is that each list must store the values of each set and to do that I have to store the list when I first meet the number of the set ( # -------) and this is why I add the `objSuite` of the current set within that if-statement

Comment: @AdamAmin I'm telling you why you're getting the results you're getting. Perhaps use a boolean to mark whether or not you've found a (# ------) or something else.